# Nativescript & Webpack - load a external template

Tags: webpack, angular2-nativescript

I want to load an external template in a Nativescript / angular2 project bundled with Webpack.

I just did a proof of concept using the hello world application NS guys offer and following the documentation https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/bundling-with-webpack  but it does not work as expected:

I paste my code although it mimics what documentation says.

`webpack.config.js:`

```
var bundler = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = bundler.getConfig({
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

`app.component.ts:`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: require("./app.component.html")
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

`app.component.html`is in `app` folder at the same level than `app.component.ts`

Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "./app.component.html"
File "/data/data/org.nativescript.groceries/files/app/bundle.js line 54749, colum 174
```

it should be straightforward. Some ideas what I am missing? If I inline the template code everything works properly.

Comment: try to `import` instead `require`-ing it

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can use the templates for your component.

1. Import the template

   ```
   import appComponent from './app.component.html';
   ...

   @Component({
   template : headerTemplate,
   ...
   })
   ```
2. use templateUrl

   You can use templateUrl instead template. Webpack will take care to require the template for you. The path is **relative** to component.

   ```
   @Component({
     templateUrl: './header.component.html',
   })
   ```